# iPhone SDK screen size returns different results using similar syntax

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm new to Objective C for iPhone. I tried the following code to get the screen size, however the code below returns two different result:

```
CGRect screenRect = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
NSLog(@"width: %d", screenRect.size.width);
NSUInteger width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
NSUInteger height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
NSLog(@"width: %d", width);
```

The first NSLog outputs 0, while the last one outputs 320. Why are they different? Does it have something to do with pointers? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%d is for decimal and you're trying to print a float. Try

```
CGRect screenRect = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds; 
NSLog(@"width: %f", screenRect.size.width); 
float width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width; 
NSLog(@"width: %f", width);
```

Comment: Man, I knew it was something simple. Thanks so much!

Comment: I realize I'm WAAAY late to the party, but isn't `%d` for integer?

Answer (score 1):

[CGRect.size.width](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGSize) is a CGFloat.  If you use %f in your format string, you will get 320.

Answer (score 0):

The [bounds](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/bounds) property is a structure of type [CGRect](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGRect). I think since NSLog doesn't know how to print this, it prints a 0. The size member is a structure of type [CGSize](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGSize). You can print CGSize's members because they are simply CGFLoats, or floats.

**EDIT**: Oh, I see what the problem is now. Thought you were printing the structure itself. Misread that.